# How to calculate checkbox price if it is checked

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm stuck with these checkbox calculate function. What I want to do is the checkbox that being checked will display at the total price along with the value of textview value of ticket for adult and child. But i did not find the solution to do it. The error is, when i click the checkbox, it will jump back to home screen. But when i calculate the hall and the ticket price only, it shows the total.

Here is my code:

```java
public class movie1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie1);
    }

    public void calculateTDEE(View view) {

        String hall;

        RadioButton rb1 = findViewById(R.id.rb1);
        if (rb1.isSelected())
            hall = "2D";

        else
            hall = "MX4D";

        double sum =0;

        CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
        if(cb1.isChecked()){
            sum = 14.50;
        }
        CheckBox cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb2);
        if(cb2.isChecked()){
            sum=18.50;
        }
        CheckBox cb3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb3);
        if(cb3.isChecked()){
            sum=14.50;
        }

            EditText etAdult = findViewById(R.id.etAdult);
            int adult = Integer.parseInt(etAdult.getText().toString());

            EditText etChild = findViewById(R.id.etChild);
            int child = Integer.parseInt(etChild.getText().toString());

            double BMR = 0.00;
            if (hall.equals("2D"))
                BMR = (10.00 * child) + (21.50 * adult) + sum;
            else
                BMR = (18.00 * child) + (30.50 * adult ) + sum;

            double TDEE = BMR;

            TextView tvResult = findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
            tvResult.setText("Your order already booked! Your Total Price is " + (double) TDEE + " Pay at Counter");
        }
```

Comment: Show your error logs. It may be crash

Comment: Assign empty value for hall,  String hall=""; or check not null when using hall. either way it will solve problem

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you're doing or what triggers this code (is it a checkbox listener?) but you have a few unsafe operations:

```
int adult = Integer.parseInt(etAdult.getText().toString());
```

`parseInt` [will throw a `NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) if the contents of that `EditText` don't represent a valid integer, e.g. if it's empty or has text in it. So you need to catch that exception and handle it (e.g. treat the value as zero), and you need to do that for both of the text boxes you're parsing.

---

```
EditText etAdult = findViewById(R.id.etAdult);
```

All `findViewById` calls can return *null* if the view with that ID isn't found, so make sure all your views are in the layout. Calling `getText()` or `setText()` on a null variable will cause a `NullPointerException`. It's suspicious that your method takes a `View` parameter that you never use, are you supposed to be calling `findViewById` on that?

Look in your error logs, if your app is restarting (which it sounds like, if the first Activity is appearing again) then it's probably a crash, and the error message will tell you exactly what's causing it and where to look.